# Logical output of CMOS circuit

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, cmos

What would be the output of the following CMOS circuit?

My answer is coming out to be R(P+Q).

[image: CMOS Circuit]

Comment: Generally, the bulk of the NMOS Q,R, and the PMOS R would be connected to GND, supply. This does not change the logic function of the circuit.

Comment: User2, The pullup and pulldown sections are all correct opposites of each other, as they should be. That's sanity check #1. On the left side, the logic feeding into the right side inverter is /P + /Q/R (looking only at the PFET pullups.) This is the same as /(P(Q+R)). This gets inverted by the right side. So the Y output is P(Q+R) as I see it.

Comment: user2961109 - Hi, I have "rolled back" your recent edit where you removed the image from the question. That image is an essential part of the question, and removing it would prevent others from understanding your question in future. Please don't do that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first half of the circuit is P+QR and the second is a NOT gate, therefore the final answer will be
$$
\overline{P+QR}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Split your analysis between PMOS and NMOS switches:

[image]

Turning the NMOS switches ON: for the **X** node to be pulled to **0**, **P** must be **1** *AND* **Q** *OR* **R** must be **1**.

Turning the PMOS switches ON: For the **X** node to be pulled to **1**, **P** must be **0** *OR* **Q** *AND* **R** must be **0**.

This fills the table perfectly (there is no short circuit and no floating output):

```
P Q R | X | Y
0 0 0 | 1 | 0
0 0 1 | 1 | 0
0 1 0 | 1 | 0
0 1 1 | 1 | 0
1 0 0 | 1 | 0
1 0 1 | 0 | 1
1 1 0 | 0 | 1
1 1 1 | 0 | 1
```

So, the correct answer, after the inverter at the output is:

$$
Y = P (Q + R)
$$